# jQuery Plugin Return this.each and add function property to each object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, jquery-plugins

Is it possible to create a jQuery plugin that returns this.each for multiple matches allowing me to add a function property to each object within the each loop?  I want to call this function later directly off of the object.

For example, here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
(function ( $ ) {
  $.fn.roflcopter = function( options ) {

    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).addClass('lol');
        $(this).getMyValue = function(e){
            return returnMyFilteredValue($(this));
        }
    });

    function returnMyFilteredValue(elem){
        return $(elem).val().replace("cat", "dog");
    }

  };
}( jQuery ));
```

I then want to in a document.ready function call this:

```
$("input.coolStuff").roflcopter();
var value = $("input.coolStuff").first().getMyValue();
```

Is this possible?  I get an error stating that getMyValue is not a function.

Comment: `.each()` just returns the object it was given. Use `.map()` if you want to loop over elements and return what the function returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor change: just place getMyValue on 'this' and not on $(this) and access it by

```
$("input.coolStuff").first()[0].getMyValue()
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  How come it won't work on $(this)?  And why do I have to pass it an array index for it to work?

Comment: you can store getMyValue  on 'object = $(this)' but then you will have to store this object somewhere to use later. Since you did not store so its lost. so later when you try accessing it from $("input.coolStuff").first() it wont be found. Since I stored it in "this" which is actualy a html node object then it will be stored in dom and $("input.coolStuff").first()[0] gives that node object where I stored

Comment: Yes, but I didn't have to do all of that.  Simply this works: `this.getMyValue = function(){
    return returnMyValue($this);
   }` works fine too when accessing like this:  `$("input.coolStuff").each(function(e){
      str += $(this)[0].getMyValue() + "\n";
     });`

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) to store and call a function at an element; `Function.prototype.bind()` to set `this` to `$(this)` within `.each()` at `getMyValue`

```js
$(function() {
  (function($) {
    $.fn.roflcopter = function(options) {
      return this.each(function() {
        $(this).addClass("lol");
        function getMyValue(e) {
          return returnMyFilteredValue(this);
        };
        $(this).data().getMyValue = getMyValue.bind($(this));
      });

      function returnMyFilteredValue(elem) {
        return elem.val(function(index, val) {
          return val.replace("cat", "dog");
        })
      }

    };
  }(jQuery));

  $("input.coolStuff").roflcopter();
  var value = $("input.coolStuff").first().data().getMyValue();
  console.log(value, value.val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input class="coolStuff" value="cat" />
<input class="coolStuff" value="cat" />
```