# jQuery plugin return this.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I am bulding a plugin let's call it `ptest` and I want to be able to call it with:

```
$(".myClassName").ptest();
```

Since I am using attributes from the element on which the plugin is called, lets say `data-attribute` I now know that returning `this.each(...);` is a **must**.
Here is my code:

```
(function($){
    var op;
    $.fn.ptest = function(options) {
        op = $.extend({
            target: null,
            attribute: null
        }, options);

        return this.each(function(){
            op.target = $(this);
            op.attribute = op.target.attr("data-attribute");
            bind();
        });
    };
    function bind(){
        op.target.find('.clickable').bind('click',log);
    }
    function log(){
        console.log(op.attribute);
    }
}(jQuery));
```

I know that by having `op` as a global variable it will always retain the last value for the `attribute` and the `target`. How can I make the op variable retain the correct value for each element of `.myClassName` while being able to access each `op` from `log` or `bind` functions?

I sense i need to declare the functions and the variable in a different way, but how?

---

I have looked at a lot of different questions and tutorials, here are some:

- http://devheart.org/articles/tutorial-creating-a-jquery-plugin/
- [jQuery plugin development - return this.each issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962363/jquery-plugin-development-return-this-each-issue)
- [jQuery Plugin Return this.each and add function property to each object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415583/jquery-plugin-return-this-each-and-add-function-property-to-each-object)
- https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/ (of course)

Comment: What do you use `bind` and `log` for?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in my question i just left the essential code, in the real one i use the `op.attribute` to query a database, so i need each attribute to be correct

Comment: With respect, that doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can you describe better what you want to  know?

Comment: `op.target.find('.clickable').bind('click',log);` binds a click event that triggers `log`

Comment: Ah, true. It just seems like with a bigger picture, we'd be able to help you more. But the answer below addresses what's actually asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `bind` and `log` really need access to the specific element in the loop, then you need to define them within the `each` callback, and make `op` local to that callback:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.ptest = function(options) {

        return this.each(function(){
            var op = $.extend({
                target: $(this)
            }, options);
            op.attribute = op.target.attr("data-attribute");
            bind();

            function bind(){
                op.target.find('.clickable').bind('click',log);
            }
            function log(){
                console.log(op.attribute);
            }
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

But depending on how you're using `bind` and `log`, there may be other options available.

Comment: that did it, for some reason I thought I had tried it!